# Problems in triangles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, triangles

Proof : In an acute angle triangle $ABC$, $AP$ is the altitude. Circle drawn with $AP$ as its diameter cut the side $AB$ and $AC$ at $D$ and $E$,   respectively then length of $DE$ is equal to 
(Area of Triangle) /Circumradius

Comment: We need something more in the given.

Comment: I have added the image

Comment: This is January 1, not April 1.

Comment: @Pokemon Ash I think your picture drown for another problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\measuredangle AED=\measuredangle APD=90^{\circ}-\measuredangle BPD=\measuredangle B,$$
which says that $$\Delta ABC\sim\Delta AED.$$

Thus, $$\frac{DE}{BC}=\frac{AD}{AC},$$ which says
$$DE=\frac{BC\cdot AD}{AC}=\frac{BC\cdot AP\sin\measuredangle B}{2R\sin\measuredangle B}=\frac{S_{\Delta ABC}}{R}.$$

Comment: You're referring to the image the OP meant to give, not the one they gave, right? ;)

Comment: Yes, of course. Happy New Year! :)

Comment: Sorry for the mistake

Comment: It's all right. Happy New Year!